# Python: How could this be written in a less verbose form?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to prepend a `0` to `birthday['month']` if it's between 1 and 9, using Python:

```
if len(birthday['month']) == 1:
    birthday['month'] = "0" + birthday['month']
```

Example:
If `birthday['month']` is `7`, the expected output is `07`

**Note:** `birthday[month]` is a `string`.

Comment: What type is birthday['month']? int or string?

Comment: @mhawke it's a `string`.

Comment: Great, now we can tell which answers are correct :)

Comment: @mhawke so many great answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `format` directly like this

```
birthday[month] = format(birthday[month], '>02')
```

If you want to convert it for display it's more natural to put the format inside the text

```
print "foo bar {:>02} baz".format(birthday[month])
```

Comment: +1 for the `>` that allows this statement to work with strings

Answer (score 5):

You can do it as:

```
'{:02}'.format(int(birthday[month]))
```

You don't need to check if the length is 1 or not. This code by itself will replace your code in your question

Comment: Gotta love Python! Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this? It just throws a `ValueError` when I try it.

Comment: This is wrong. It expects that birthday['month'] is an int. Looking at the OP code sample it is a string. Try `'{:02}'.format(int(birthday['month']))` instead.

Comment: @mhawke is right. This won't work with a string (I mistakenly tried it on the Python interpreter using an `int`). @user2357112's answer above works for strings.

Comment: `'{:>02}'.format(birthday[month])` works too! (I just learned that from @gnibbler's answer below). This is so cool!

Answer (score 1):

```
birthday['month'] = birthday['month'].zfill(2)
```

The [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) string method pads a numeric string with zeros to a given width. (It handles signs correctly, too, if you use it on a string with a positive or negative sign. You don't need that here, though.)

Comment: Thanks! Works really well with strings that hold numbers (would not work an `int` though, in case someone missed that).